# Php download facebook images with fopen

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to run this code on my VPS

```
    <?php 
    function curl_get_contents($url, array $opts = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla Firefox 20.0',
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
    );
    $opts = $opts + $defaults;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_get_contents('http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/58678_10151328142003680_1939974573_n.jpg');

?>
```

when i run it, there's a infinite loop and i don't understand why. the function works with every image url, but not with facebook. Any Suggestion?

Comment: have you tried curl or simply file_get_contents?

Comment: I don't think Facebook allows you to fetch an image without first having a session.

Comment: yes, i tried several times curl and file_get_contents i think it's more appropriate for text file and no images

Comment: Borjne is correct: When I go to that url with a browser that is not logged into facebook, I get "invalid request". When I go to it when I'm logged in, I get the image.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
<?php
function curl_get_contents($url, array $opts = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla Firefox 20.0'
    );
    $opts = $opts + $defaults;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_get_contents('link to facebook image');
?>
```

Comment: I tried this solution with echo curl_get_contents('http://sphotos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/148917_10151187261222096_2028916617_n.jpg'); but i'm still getting nothing

Comment: Works as expected on my end -- Can you add the CURLOPT_VERBOSE option to it and tell me the output? :)

Comment: Hi, i added it here function curl_get_contents($url, array $opts = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla Firefox 20.0',
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
    );
    $opts = $opts + $defaults;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

    return curl_exec($ch);
}

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo curl_get_contents('http://sphotos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/148917_10151187261222096_2028916617_n.jpg');

Comment: That is correct, now just execute it and show the output please (edit your original post and put it in there)

Comment: is it correct? i'm sorry i'm a java developer and i'm not very good at php

Comment: I tried it again. Nothing to do, when i execute it (open the page where the php code is) it's only displaying me a broken image icon, nothing else

Comment: Remove the line that sets the content-type to image/jpeg.

Comment: Maybe have i to install some components?

Comment: Ok, i deleted it, now i have only a blank page

Comment: No, cURL should be installed on most new releases of PHP by default, and unless it's a production server it would throw an error. What does `var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));` output?

Comment: Well... Enable or install it, or use a different solution.

Comment: I have installed it and run the code, infinite loop :(..... ok thank you very much for help